# May I ask someone to explain this recursion example of reversing and displaying an array. I can't picture it in my head

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to bend my mind around this example but I just can't quite see it.

It seems like a weird concept because I am just starting recursion in my program. This example is practice for my final exam on Wednesday.

```
public class revArray
{
     public static int arrayOfNum[] = {1,2,5,4,6};

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         reverse(arrayOfNum, 0);
     }

     public static void reverse(int[] nums, int index)
     {
         if(index != nums.length)

         //I feel like the index should have started as the length
         //of the array and instead of +1 it should be -1

         reverse(nums,index+1);

         System.out.print(nums[index]);
     }      
}
```

I have another example of reversing a string and it seems like it should be similar. I am pretty confused. I'm not sure what else to say really. If someone can lend me a hand I would be really thankful.

Comment: Have you tried to do it on paper?

Comment: This looks like a great opportunity to step through the code in a debugger and observe what it's doing.

Comment: Ok I will try that thank you litelite.

And alright I didn't think of that thanks for the suggestion David.

Comment: Looking at it in the debugger was really strange, the index when from 0 - 4 and then 4 - 0 @David

Comment: because there isn't anything that decreases the index in the code

Comment: This code doesn't actually reverse the array. It just prints the array reversed.

Comment: @KyleGoertzen There is no need for *decreasing* the index value. Java is pass-by-value, so every recursive call establishes a *new* `index` parameter with a new value (`+1`). When the call returns, the earlier invocation on the call stack will still have the "old" value.

Comment: @KyleGoertzen: Why is that strange?  Each recursive method call adds 1 to the index for that called method.  When you leave that called method, you're back to the previous method call where the index wasn't increased by 1.  What's *strange* is why this method is using recursion for this at all instead of just a loop.

Comment: @David Not strange at all, as this is an *example* in recursion, not an example of how to do this the best way. It's an educational example used to teach recursion.

Comment: @Andreas: Teaching *when* to use recursion is as valuable as teaching *how*.  "This is how you do it, but you shouldn't do this" doesn't seem like a very helpful learning exercise :)  Something like a binary search tree seems like a more practical example.

Comment: Ok it just clicked in my mind, thanks everybody :)

Comment: Names of classes should be UpperCamelCase, i.e. RevArray

Answer (score 2):

In java methods are invoked and in this process there is a `callee` method and the `called` method. Each invokation of a method is backed by an entry in a `Stack`. Once the `called` method completes the execution the execution control reaches back to the `callee` and the very next operation of the `callee` is executed. Remember till the time `called` method does not completes its execution `called` method execution is halted (actually its maintained just below the entry of the `called` method in stack). Upon completion of execution the entry for the `called` method is popped out of stack.

Code needs below correction

```
if(index != nums.length -1) // condition should have a  '-1'.
```

or

```
if(index != nums.length){
      reverse(nums,index+1);
     System.out.print(nums[index]);
}
```

I am moving ahead with 1st one. (-1 in the condition).

Recursion is a process of a method invoking itself. Both the `callee` and the `called` methods are same. Now in your code the starting value of `index` is 0.

```
     if(index != nums.length)
     reverse(nums,index+1); // execution control reaching this statement pushes the current instance of method execution in  stack.
```

The process of pushing each invoked instances of the (same) on the stack with value of index being plus 1 as compared to each previously invoked method instance is continued till the condition `index != nums.length -1` is true. The next executable statement of printing is not yet reached for any method till now.

The method instance for which the condition `index != nums.length -1` becomes false the control reaches the printing statement and `nums[index-1]` is printed out. Once this is done then the entry for this method instance is popped out of stack and execution control reaches the printing statement of the `callee` method which is there now at the `top` of the stack. Like this methods are popped out and printing statement of all the method instances is executed till all the entries of the method are popped out.

Answer (score 0):

The key to recursion is that you are calling the same method over and over to eventually reach an end condition.

To implement this, the JVM implements a call stack. When you call a method, the execution state is "saved" whilst the calling method executes. This can be done over and over (the stack). When a method completes and returns, the previous execution state is restored and execution continues.

Looking at the comment in your code, you're wondering if "the index should have started as the length of the array". Well, notice the location of the recursive call - it happens *before* the `System.out.println`.

So, you can look at how the call stack works.

```
reverse(nums, 0)
-reverse(nums, 1)
--reverse(nums, 2)
---reverse(nums, 3)
----reverse(nums, 4)
-----reverse(nums, 5)
------(returns)
-----prints "6"
----prints "4"
---prints "5"
--prints "2"
-prints "1"
```

In this manner, the recursive calls are indeed printing the array in reverse order.

In contrast, if the `System.out.println` had been *before* the recursive call, then yes - you would have needed to walk the array in the opposite direction.

By the way I added braces in your code to fix a bug and make it clearer. Hope this helps!

```
public class RevArray
{
    public static int arrayOfNum[] = {1,2,5,4,6};

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        reverse(arrayOfNum, 0);
    }

    public static void reverse(int[] nums, int index)
    {
        if(index != nums.length) {

            // this indeed works :)
            reverse(nums, index + 1);

            System.out.print(nums[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so your program starts at void main() wich calls reverse(arrayOfNum,0)

at this point the first link of the reverse function i.e if(index != nums.length) is called the BASE CONDITION. It is basically the condition that is used to see when we should exit a recursive function.

So when you first call reserve(arrayOfNum,0) i.e revers ({1,2,5,4,6},0),
it checks whether the index (i.e 0) is not qual to the length of the array (here it is 5).
Then it calls reverse(nums, index+1)
now even though the next statement is System.out.println(), it will NOT execute untill the reverse function (which we just recursively called) finishes executing.

So what happens now is, reverse is called again with reverse({1,2,5,4,6},1)
once again the base condition is not satisfied...and hence reverse is called again for reverse({1,2,5,4,6},2) and then again for reverse({1,2,5,4,6},3) and then for reverse({1,2,5,4,6},4) and then for reverse({1,2,5,4,6},5)

in reverse reverse({1,2,5,4,6},5) the BASE CONDITION is met, ie here index (5) == nums.length(5), hence the recursive reverse function is NOT call and staright away we call System.out.println(nums[index]), here index was 5 so it prints nums[5] which is 6 (the index might be off by one here, just verify that once).
Once this finishes execution the previous reverse({1,2,5,4,6},4) resumes execution at the print statement and that prints num[4] which is 4...and so on

So the final output whould be 6,4,5,2,1

Though i think the program might be off by an index of 1.

As for your comment,
//I feel like the index should have started as the length
 //of the array and instead of +1 it should be -1

If we did do that, then the array would end up printing in the order it was given instead of reverse, because as i mention earlier, the print statement wont execute until all the underlying recursive method finishes execution

Answer (score 0):

I understand all of what you are saying and for extra practice I solved it another way.

```
public class array
{
     public static int[] nums = {1,3,6,3,5};

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         reverse(nums,4);
     }

     public static int[] reverse(int[] arr, int index)
     {
         if(index < 0)
         {
             return arr;
         }
         System.out.print(arr[index]);
         return reverse(arr, index-1);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Its just another way of doing it and it is correct. Just that if you processing after the recursive call then that processing is done while revisiting the method and if you do it before the recursive call you do it on the first visit to the method. Suggested next topic is Back tracking to understand more of post recursive call processing